# HashMap object in value

Tags: hashmap, key-value

My question is, how do I "unwrap" a hashmap value object?

I am able to create, save, and load the hashmap.  I am doing a populate then select employee to calculate pay.

```
Map<Integer, Employee> hm = new HashMap<>(); 

hID++;
  System.out.println("Enter employee first name:  ");
  String nameF = sc.next();

  System.out.println("Enter employee last name");
  String nameL = sc.next();

  hourly = new HourlyEmployee();
  Employee hEmp = new Employee(hourly, nameF, nameL);

  System.out.println(hEmp.getName());

  hm.put(hID, hEmp);

/*
save()
exit
run
load()
select employee, enter ID
loops to find match
*/

Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Employee>> set = hm.entrySet();

  do
  {
     System.out.println("Enter the empoyee ID");
     int id = sc.nextInt();

       if (id >= 1000 && id < 1999)
       {
          System.out.println("*****  HOURLY  *****");

          for (Map.Entry<Integer, Employee> entry : set)
       {
       if (entry.getKey().equals(id))
       {
           // this is where I run into the issues.  all I get
           // with the value is the hash location.  I can't
           // figure out how to unwrap into the hourly class
           // as the object, then edit the values then wrap again.
           System.out.println(entry.getValue());
           // I understand this is not how you get what I
           // need.  But this does give me:
           //
           // "edu.umsl.composition.++++++++.Employee@682a0b20"       

       }

}
```

See the code comments.

Comment: No weird "wrapping" has happened to the value. *Any* Employee would print like that, HashMap value or not, because you didn't write a toString method. Just use the object like you normally would.

Comment: What I am trying to say is class HourlyEmployee is part of Employee, with out inheritance.  I want to be able to access HourlyEmployee methods

Comment: Do whatever you would have done if the HashMap wasn't involved. (Also, your class composition doesn't make any sense.)

Comment: Thats not helpful.  What doesn't make sense about it?  I'm trying to learn.  This is partial code from 3 different classes.  

Main Class (main method and menus)

Employee Class > 1. Hourly Class
                              2. Salary Class
                              3. Commission Class

Comment: I can access Employee methods, but not the HourlyEmployee methods

Comment: At least I think this is C# code. It's obviously not copy/paste from compiling code so the typos could change the interpretation of it depending on which are the typos.

Comment: @Joshua No, this is not C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: *partial code

```
 public void selectEmployee() {
    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Employee>> set = hm.entrySet();

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the empoyee ID");

        int id = sc.nextInt();

        if (id >= 1000 && id < 1999) {
            System.out.println("*****  HOURLY  *****");

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Employee> entry : set) {
                if (entry.getKey().equals(id)) {

                    int key = entry.getKey();
                    Employee hEmp = entry.getValue();

                    hEmp.getHourlyEmp().getGrossPay();

                }

            }
```

Comment: I should have know this.  I was over thinking things.